# Serial terminal over ethernet

Tags: linux, remote-access, grub, serial

Well, my idea is I would like to have access to grub over Ethernet/Internet, I've found two possible solutions:

1. Converter RS232 to Ethernet ([1](http://cgi.ebay.com/RS232-TCP-IP-Ethernet-Serial-Device-Server-Converter-/280555738680?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item41526cd638)) which looks like to have its own live, I mean it is independent on computer, than I should be able to connect to serial console and do what i want to do
2. Use classic dial-up modem, than somehow convert it to Ethernet and than use it

Have you got any experiences with stuff like that? Any others suggestions? Or am I wrong?
I've eliminated iLO because of price.

Comment: A starting point, http://netmedia.com/siteplayer/telnet/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Moxa's](http://www.moxa.com/) serial to ethernet adapters to connect RS232 CNC machines to our network at the shop. You run client software (the Windows Nport software or the Linux TTY library) to get view the serial port on the remote machine.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm thinking about, seems like my solution number one, but not the chines version. I'm glad to hear than it works!

Comment: Note, however, that Moxas aren't cheap (I think they go for around $120 a pop) but they're pretty solid devices overall.

Comment: +1 for Moxa, they are really solid and I've never seen a broken one.I also had good experience with Black Box and Digi for serial port boxes.

Answer (score 1):

One nice option is to use serial over LAN. This requires support (IPMI) from motherboard, but many recent server motherboards have this feature nowadays.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got quite old motherboard, not the server one, it's just kind of home server. And I don't have IPMI.